# How to get original string by string_view in c++?

Tags: c++, string, string-view

For example,

```
std::string_view strv{ "Hello" };
strv.remove_prefix(1);
```

The original string should be "Hello".
I tried using `strv.data()` and `std::string str(strv.begin(), strv.end());`
I can only get "ello" instead of "Hello".

Comment: You remove the first character (h) with `strv.remove_prefix(1)`, why would you expect anything other than "ello"?

Comment: The `data()` member returns a pointer to the first element of the view, not to the first element of the original string. Same goes for the iterators. The reason is that a view is like a window open on an actual container, not the container itself.

Comment: `strv.data() - 1`? but it is now outside of the view...

Comment: Does anyone know if it would be undefined behavior to access `strv.data() - 1`?

Comment: @JohnFilleau Not sure, the location is outside of the view but remains valid (not outside of the string) so...

Comment: @JohnFilleau It should be fine, as `data` points into an array to a position where `data() - 1` is still inside that same array.  AFAIK the pointer arithmetic rules say that is okay.

Comment: @mdf because I just expect the view is changed, I didnt expect that the original string is changed.

Answer (score 1):

I only found two methods right now.

1. use a variable(e.g. `string str`) to store original string then use use string_view.  When you need the original string, use `str`.
2. use a variable(e.g. `int removed_len`) to record the length of removed prefixes. Then when you need the original string `strv.data() - removed_len` is the start place of the original string.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The `"Hello"` you use to construct `strv` is your original string. However, you never actually instantiate that string, making it a prvalue. If you want to keep a copy of your original string, try something like:

```cpp
std::string str{"Hello"};
std::string_view strv{str};
strv.remove_prefix(1);
```

`str` will hold your original string.

Comment: Is it possible to find an original anonymous string?